# Ruby on Rails: How to pass dynamically-assigned link IDs to controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry if I mess something up, but I'm new here, so bear with me.

Here's kinda what I want to do. I want to dynamically assign ID tags to links based on the user ID's in my database. Then based on which link that I click, I want that link to call the controller helper and pass in its ID to the helper method.

So far, I'm able to dynamically assign each link for each user, but my problem is when I click the link and it calls the controller method **callThis** with the ID, it gets the last user's (the last user in the database) ID instead of the user ID of the link that I clicked.

My question is, how do I get it to send the ID of the link that I click, and not the ID of the last user in the database?

Here's my code. 
**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="profile"></div>
<table>
<% @users.each do |u| %>
    <% if !u.nil? and u.department_id == department.id %>
      <tr class="<%= department.id %>" style="display:none;text-align:left;">
        <td>
          <a href="#id-<%= u.id %>" id="id-<%= u.id %>" onclick="<%= callThis(u.id) %>; refresh();">
            <%= "#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}" %> 
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
</table>
<script>
  function refresh(){
    $('#profile').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'profile')) %>"); 
  }
</script>
```

**professors_controller.rb**

```
class ProfessorsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :callThis
  helper_attr :get_id
  attr_accessor :get_id

  def index
    @departments = Department.all
    @users = User.with_role :Professor
    @search  = @users.search(params[:q])
    @result = @search.result
    @id = 0
  end

  def callThis(id)
    @id = id
  end
  def get_id
    @id
  end
end
```

**profile.html.erb**

```
<%= get_id.to_s %>
```

Comment: You're doing it all wrong, `callThis(id)` instead of being called at click, is called once for every user in `@users` variable, on the server, not on client. What exactly do you want this link to do?

Comment: @MarekLipka I want the link to call the callThis(id) function whenever it's clicked, and send the link's ID into the method so it can be shared by the profile.html.erb.

I'm probably not doing it right, I'm a newbie at RoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just pass the id back in the params hash and use ajax to render the profile view?

```
   <td>
     <%= link_to "#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}", name_of_your_path({:user_id => u.id), :"data-remote" => true %>

    </td>
```

then in your controller

```
class ProfessorsController < ApplicationController
  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
 end
```

then create a view with a js extension. "profile.js.erb" and in that file

```
$('#profile').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'profile')) %>");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on your suggestions yet. For the first block of code, I think you're missing a closing curly bracket }. Where did you mean to put it?

Also, I'm not really good at routes yet. If I swapped _name_of_your_path_ with professors_path, what would I put in routes.db to match the route to the profile method?

Comment: yea im  missing a curly brace.I would use that link_to helper instead of your <a> </a> tag. Posting your routes file might help but I image you having something like resources :professors, in which case your route would be professor_path(a_professor) where the variable a_professor is an instance of professor in your case the variable `u'. Then in your controller the params hash will contain params[:id] where the id is the professors value.

Comment: I ended up using cookies to get it working. It's probably not the best idea, but I got it working.